# Uma resposta com vários votos negativos deve ser excluída?

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise

Apareceu esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/119742/27190) na fila de publicações de baixa qualidade, analisei a resposta, porem ela poderia ser melhorada adicionando mais informações a respeito da pergunta, mas este não foi o motivo de eu ter recomendado a exclusão da mesma.

Percebi que a resposta possui vários votos negativos, e a resposta não parece estar errada, só carece em informações, poderia melhorar, sendo assim achei melhor recomendar a exclusão da resposta para evitar que o AR receba mais votos negativos, visto que não havia nenhum comentário a respeito de sua publicação sugerindo alguma melhoria em parte de quem deu o voto negativo.

Entretanto esta minha atitude de ter marcado para exclusão foi correta? O que eu deveria fazer a respeito da situação citada? Que ações eu deveria tomar?

Nota:

> O usuário [jbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/jbueno) me
>   sugeriu trazer a discussão no meta, então decidir criar o tópico.

Comment: Se o critério for só "ter vários votos negativos" eu acho que não deve ser excluída.

Comment: Votar negativo. Dar um toque. Passar pra próxima pergunta. Algo mais? Não. "Deletar pra evitar mais negativos" não existe, não de forma terceirizada.

Comment: Se achou algum problema que acha que pode melhorar, você pode formular uma nova resposta com explicando os pontos negativos da outra resposta, não precisa necessariamente apontar a resposta com problemas, recomendo que apenas cite como coisas "não recomendadas". Excluir por ser "incorreta" não me parece muito o caminho, só excluo mesmo quando há problemas como SPAM, não tiver haver com o assunto, ou quando for rude/ofensiva. Mas se a resposta tenta responder ao problema, mas falta algo ou se confunde em algo os downvotes são mais que o suficiente pra indicar que não é uma boa resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento neste caso não era a exclusão por ser incorreta, mais sim para evitar que o AR recebesse mais negativos, até o momento que ele formulasse uma nova resposta mais completa. De qualquer forma a resposta já foi excluída, não sei se foi meu voto ou se foi o próprio AR.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho não há problema em receber vários downvotes, a partir do momento que ele mesmo deletar a postagem ele irá recuperar o score, como se nunca tivesse recebido downvote algum ali na postagem. Downvote não é uma arma maligna usada pra fazer as pessoas se sentirem mal ou passar constrangimento, é uma ferramenta pra ajudar a definir "qualidade". Esse tipo de downvote me parece totalmente justo. O problema são os votos dados em respostas e perguntas boas porque teve algum desentendimento com o autor da postagem (picuinha).

Comment: Aqui é onde eu posso fazer pergunta para discussões?

Comment: @Vinicius, isso, aqui no Meta pode perguntar o que quiser sobre o funcionamento do site, abrir discussões ou pedir suporte. . . . Se a gente está distraido não percebe a mudança de colorido no site principal para escala de cinza aqui no Meta, mas bom, na logomarca ali encima fica clara a mudança, são dois sites diferentes, um filho do outro.

Comment: @brasofilo Hummm, eu achei que aqui era um local pra fazer perguntas pra se criar um debate, não existe um local assim por aqui não? Tem umas perguntas que a gente quer a opinião dos outros mas não pode perguntar

Comment: @Vinicius, acho que precisa do [chat] então. Fazer perguntas de programação pedindo "opinião" é off-topic (fora de escopo) no site principal. Aqui no Meta a gente discute e opina como funciona o site principal (tipo administração mesmo, nada de programação). Lá no chat pode falar do que quiser e pedir orientação de como perguntar no site principal ou aqui no meta ;)

Comment: @Vinicius, tem certas coisas de programação que vai ser melhor ir perguntar em outros sites. Aqui no [pt.so] não pode perguntas do tipo "Qual a melhor tecnologia?", ou "Que livros devo ler?", ou "Qual carreira devo seguir?" . . . . Qualquer dúvida maluca que tiver, pergunta no chat que não tem problema

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Uma resposta com vários votos negativos deve ser excluída?

## Não.

Devemos votar para excluir:

- comentários em forma de resposta;
- agradecimentos em forma de resposta;
- esclarecimentos em forma de resposta;
- novas perguntas em forma de resposta;
- respostas extremamente pobres/duplicadas quando já existem várias outras.

> achei melhor recomendar a exclusão da resposta para evitar que o AR receba mais votos negativos

Esse **não é um motivo válido** para excluir uma resposta.

> Que ações eu deveria tomar?

Vote positivo. Deixe um comentário. Edite para melhorar a formatação. Conferir outras respostas do mesmo usuário para ver se é um problema recorrente.

---

Observações:

- em caso de Spam é importante ***Sinalizar como Spam***. O sistema e os moderadores vão tomar ações específicas contra isso e que não são simplesmente deletar a pergunta/resposta.
- se a Resposta for só um link e for uma informação útil, faça uma sinalização personalizada pedindo para um moderador converter aquilo em Comentário; creio que isto fica por conta do leitor, se achar que merece ser removido ou não.

Comment: Excelente explicação, com tópicos e bem organizada. Não esqueça de citar sobre os SPAMMERS =)

Comment: Lembrando que em alguns casos, você pode sinalizar para o moderador e deixar uma mensagem sugerindo conversão para comentário. Muitas vezes o conteúdo não é resposta, mas realmente agrega algum valor. Neste caso, como comentario, atinge o propósito, e de brinde o autor da postagem se livra dos negativos e não perde a tentativa de ajudar. Obviamente, como eu disse, que isso só faz sentido quando a informação agrega algum valor.

Comment: @Guilherme, adicionei uma observação sobre o Spam, que é outra praia completamente

Comment: Entendo que é uma praia diferente, mas ainda sim nenhuma é igual a outra, mas todas levam ao motivos de serem removidas =)

Comment: Sem falar que outras pessoas podem aprender que algo não se aplica a tal questão. Em resumo o voto negativo diz "não use isso", o positivo diz "use isto".

Comment: @Guilherme, sim, mas spam tem uma sinalização específica e que *não é* o deletar normal. Com ela, os moderadores e o sistema vão *destruir* o post e a conta associada.

Comment: @brasofilo ah sim entendi, só uma coisa, nem sempre a conta é deletada

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, isso, se for venda de pílulas, delete total, se for auto-promoção descarada ou similar, medidas administrativas. Nem sempre é o que acontece, mas acho que a sinalização de SPAM (all caps) deve ser reservada só pro caso das pílulas e dos xMovies.

Comment: @brasofilo Entendi, ainda não vi coisas do gênero aqui, mas dariam ótimas perolas pra comentar no chat, hehehe. Obrigado pela explicação!

Comment: _"respostas extremamente pobres/duplicadas quando já existem várias outras."_ Tipo essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121760/3117

Comment: A resposta era: _"Não, é uma linguagem de marcação."_ Na íntegra, isso era tudo.